# Custom Convolution

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

Suppose that i have a 3x3 image and i have a 2x2 kernel size. I want a whitenoiseconvolution2d that would work in a sense that:

1. the value on the [1,1] (row index, column index) location on the 2x2 kernel size is subtracted on the [0,0] (row, column) location on the 3x3 image and then taking the bessel function value of it. The result will be multiplied to the bessel function value of the index [0,0] in the kernel size  and [0,0] in the 3x3 image.
2. After this, the value on the [1,1] (row index, column index) location on the 2x2 kernel size is subtracted on the [0,1] (row, column) location on the 3x3 image and then taking the bessel function value of it. The result will be multiplied to the bessel function value of the index [0,1] in the kernel size  and [0,1] in the 3x3 image.
3. After this, the value on the [1,1] (row index, column index) location on the 2x2 kernel size is subtracted on the [1,0] (row, column) location on the 3x3 image and then taking the bessel function value of it. The result will be multiplied to the bessel function value of the index [1,0] in the kernel size  and [1,0] in the 3x3 image.
4. After this, the value on the [1,1] (row index, column index) location on the 2x2 kernel size is subtracted on the [1,1] (row, column) location on the 3x3 image and then taking the bessel function value of it. The result will be multiplied to the bessel function value of the index [1,1] in the kernel size  and [1,1] in the 3x3 image.

Then, we add all the values in a to d to give the first entry in the resulting convolution. The code below is how I think it should be implemented, and I tried troubleshooting with GPT, but its suggestions do not make sense at some point.

```
from tensorflow.math.special import bessel_j0, bessel_j1


class WhiteNoiseConvolution2D(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self,
                 filters,
                 kernels=None,
                 kernel_initializer=None,
                 strides = 1,
                 **kwargs):
        super(WhiteNoiseConvolution2D, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.filters = filters
        self.strides = strides
        self.kernels = kernels
        self.kernel_initializer = kernel_initializer
        self.initializer = tf.keras.initializers.RandomUniform(minval=2.0, maxval=5.0, seed = 300)
        self.constraint = tf.keras.constraints.min_max_norm(min_value=2.0)


    def build(self, input_shape):    
       
        # Shape: (kernel_height, kernel_width, input_channels, num_filters)
        kernel_shape = self.kernels[0], self.kernels[1], input_shape[-1], self.filters, 

        self.kernel = self.add_weight(
            shape=kernel_shape,
            initializer=self.kernel_initializer,
            trainable=True
        )
        
        print("Kernel Shape:", self.kernel.shape)

    def call(self, inputs): 
        #inputs: Batch, height, width, channel
        patches = tf.image.extract_patches(
            images=inputs,
            sizes=[1, self.kernels[0], self.kernels[1], 1],
            strides=[1, self.strides[0], self.strides[1], 1],
            rates=[1, 1, 1, 1],
            padding="SAME"
        )
        print("Input Shape:", inputs.shape)
        output_shape = tf.shape(inputs)
        
        new_patches = tf.reshape(patches, (-1, patches.shape[1], patches.shape[2], self.kernels[0], self.kernels[1], 1))
        print("New_patches shape:", new_patches.shape)
        
        k_val = self.kernel[-1, -1, :, :]
        print("K_val:", k_val.shape)
        
        f = tf.sqrt(bessel_j1(k_val - new_patches[..., None]))
        h = tf.sqrt((bessel_j0(self.kernel * new_patches[..., None])) / (self.kernel * new_patches[..., None]))
        
        output = tf.reduce_sum(f*h, axis=-1)
        print("Convolution Result Shape:", output.shape)
        new_shape = tf.concat([tf.shape(inputs)[:-1], tf.convert_to_tensor([self.filters])], axis =0)
        output = tf.reshape(output, new_shape)
        print("Output reshape:", output.shape)
        print("-------------------------------------------")
        return output
    
    def get_config(self):
        config = super(FourierConvolution2D, self).get_config()
        config.update({
            "filters":self.filters,
            "kernels":self.kernels,
            "kernel_initializer":self.kernel_initializer,
            })
        return config
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

# Specify input shape for the first layer
model.add(WhiteNoiseConvolution2D(name="conv1", filters=32, kernels=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), input_shape=(32, 32, 1)))
model.add(WhiteNoiseConvolution2D(name="conv2", filters=32, kernels=(2, 2), strides=(1, 1)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=3, strides=2, padding="SAME"))
model.add(WhiteNoiseConvolution2D(name="conv3", filters=64, kernels=(2, 2), strides=(1, 1)))
model.add(WhiteNoiseConvolution2D(name="conv4", filters=64, kernels=(2, 2), strides=(1, 1)))
```

Then I get the error

```
Epoch 1/5
Input Shape: (None, 32, 32, 1)
New_patches shape: (None, 32, 32, 3, 3, 1)
K_val: (1, 32)
Convolution Result Shape: (None, 32, 32, 3, 3, 1)
Output reshape: (None, 32, 32, 32)
-------------------------------------------
Input Shape: (None, 32, 32, 32)
New_patches shape: (None, 32, 32, 2, 2, 1)
K_val: (32, 32)
Convolution Result Shape: (None, 32, 32, 2, 2, 32)
Output reshape: (None, 32, 32, 32)
-------------------------------------------
Input Shape: (None, 16, 16, 32)
New_patches shape: (None, 16, 16, 2, 2, 1)
K_val: (32, 64)
Convolution Result Shape: (None, 16, 16, 2, 2, 32)
Output reshape: (None, 16, 16, 64)
-------------------------------------------
Input Shape: (None, 16, 16, 64)
New_patches shape: (None, 16, 16, 2, 2, 1)
K_val: (64, 64)
Convolution Result Shape: (None, 16, 16, 2, 2, 64)
Output reshape: (None, 16, 16, 64)
-------------------------------------------

Node: 'sequential_1/conv1/Reshape_1'
2 root error(s) found.
  (0) INVALID_ARGUMENT:  Input to reshape is a tensor with 294912 values, but the requested shape has 1048576
     [[{{node sequential_1/conv1/Reshape_1}}]]
     [[gradient_tape/sequential_1/conv2/Reshape_3/_26]]
  (1) INVALID_ARGUMENT:  Input to reshape is a tensor with 294912 values, but the requested shape has 1048576
     [[{{node sequential_1/conv1/Reshape_1}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_2888]
```

I have no idea now what else to do. If the process above is not clear, an equivalent photo is shown below for reference. The idea still applies as the kernel slides to neighboring sections in the image.
[image: White Noise Convolution]

The shape of the image is `(32,32,1)` where 1 is the channel.

Comment: Did you already look at [scipy.ndimage.generic_filter()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.generic_filter.html)? I think it's the easiest way to achieve what you are doing, but maybe you have a reason not to use it?

Comment: Hi @MattHall. I am thinking that using scipy inside the function will make things slower. Thus, I am restricting everything to tensorflow modules